# Interpretation of hydroplot in R (package: "hydroTSM")

Tags: r, plot, time-series, hydrotsm

I want to analyze mean daily runoff data by means of a hydroplot.
I was able to write the code for the hydroplot.

```
plot(MeteoZ,main="Runoff (m³/s) for Bad Aibling, Glonn station",xlab="Time")
```

However, I am not very sure how to interpret it. I have 3 main questions:

- Since my data was daily, how are the monthly/yearly time series made? Is that averaged per month/year? What does the y-axis represent?
- Same question for the boxplots.
- What is the value of the y-axis in the `hydroplot`? Proportion?

[image]

Comment: Is the original data an average of (m^3/s) over a day? If so, the daily would be an integration under the curve over a day (or simply the m^3/s value multiplied by the seconds in a day to give a total cubic meters of water/day). From there it's doing the same thing every day and summing to get monthly and yearly discharge. Hopefully this is what you are after.

Comment: Have you read the package vignette?  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hydroTSM/vignettes/hydroTSM_Vignette-knitr.pdf

Comment: If you want to see how those flow stats are calculated, see the R codes here https://github.com/hzambran/hydroTSM/tree/master/R. AFAIK, he used `aggregate` to do that